# Highchart map does not support IRS country code

Tags: javascript, dictionary, highcharts

My highchart map data for country code is in IRS format.

```
  series: [{
                threshold:0,
                data: data,
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
                joinBy: ['hc-key', 'country_ID'],
                name: 'Country'
            }],
```

IRS code for Switzerland is SZ whereas in ISO its CH. 
The [world.js](http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js) does not support IRS code.

Is there any json map collection that would support IRS country code?

Comment: You could always brute force a transition or update the world.js file on your server to use IRS codes.

Answer (score 0):

There's no world map in Highcharts official collection (http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/) that supports IRS codes.